# Bluetooth HFP Subscriber number information (AT+CNUM). How reliable is it?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, hfp

I'm working on a side project that connects to a phone using Bluetooth. I was going to try to get the number of the connected phone using the HFP Subscriber Number Information command (AT+CNUM). How reliable is this way of getting phone number information. Does it work on most phones or is the implementation patchy. I'd love to get an answer for someone who has implemented this for a real world product.